# Showing duration time using stopwatch in android?

Tags: android, stopwatch

I need to toast the stopwatch's value

ie.,time taken between start and stop

If i click the stop button it should toast that time duration.
How to do this?

Here i have tried some code

**chrono_meter.java**

```
public class Chrono_meter extends Activity {

Chronometer chr;
Button btn_stop_travel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chronometer_layout);

    chr = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    chr.start();

    btn_stop_travel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_inspection);
    btn_stop_travel.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
   }
    View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        chr.stop();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chr.stop();
             Toast.makeText(Chrono_meter.this, chr.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()   ;
                }
            };
```